# Adapters not working with datamapper

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-datamapper

I have the following code:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'datamapper'

DataMapper.setup :default, "postgres://localhost/mydb"
```

However, when I try and run it, I get:

LoadError: no such file to load -- dm-postgres-adapter

> /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `gem_original_require'
>
> /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `require'
>
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/dm-core-1.1.0/lib/dm-core/adapters.rb:163:in `load_adapter'
>
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/dm-core-1.1.0/lib/dm-core/adapters.rb:133:in `adapter_class'
>
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/dm-core-1.1.0/lib/dm-core/adapters.rb:13:in `new'
>
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/dm-core-1.1.0/lib/dm-core.rb:219:in `setup'

These are the gems I have installed:

> *** LOCAL GEMS ***
>
> abstract (1.0.0)
>
> actionmailer (3.0.9, 3.0.5, 2.3.5, 1.3.6)
>
> actionpack (3.0.9, 3.0.5, 2.3.5, 1.13.6)
>
> actionwebservice (1.2.6)
>
> activemodel (3.0.9, 3.0.5)
>
> activerecord (3.0.9, 3.0.5, 2.3.5, 1.15.6)
>
> activeresource (3.0.9, 3.0.5, 2.3.5)
>
> activesupport (3.0.9, 3.0.5, 2.3.5, 1.4.4)
>
> acts_as_ferret (0.4.3)
>
> addressable (2.2.6, 2.2.5)
>
> arel (2.0.10, 2.0.9)
>
> autotest (4.4.6)
>
> autotest-fsevent (0.2.4)
>
> autotest-growl (0.2.9)
>
> autotest-rails-pure (4.1.2)
>
> bcrypt-ruby (2.1.4)
>
> builder (2.1.2)
>
> bundler (1.0.10)
>
> capistrano (2.5.2)
>
> cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
>
> configuration (1.2.0)
>
> daemons (1.0.10)
>
> data_objects (0.10.6)
>
> datamapper (1.1.0)
>
> diff-lcs (1.1.2)
>
> dm-aggregates (1.1.0)
>
> dm-constraints (1.1.0)
>
> dm-core (1.2.0.rc2, 1.1.0)
>
> dm-do-adapter (1.2.0.rc2, 1.1.0)
>
> dm-migrations (1.1.0)
>
> dm-postgres-adapter (1.2.0.rc2, 1.1.0)
>
> dm-serializer (1.1.0)
>
> dm-sqlite-adapter (1.2.0.rc2, 1.1.0)
>
> dm-timestamps (1.1.0)
>
> dm-transactions (1.1.0)
>
> dm-types (1.1.0)
>
> dm-validations (1.1.0)
>
> dnssd (0.6.0)
>
> do_postgres (0.10.6)
>
> do_sqlite3 (0.10.6)
>
> erubis (2.6.6)
>
> eventmachine (0.12.10)
>
> ezcrypto (0.7.2)
>
> faraday (0.6.1)
>
> faraday_middleware (0.6.3)
>
> fastercsv (1.5.4)
>
> fastthread (1.0.1)
>
> fcgi (0.8.7)
>
> ferret (0.11.6)
>
> gem_plugin (0.2.3)
>
> hashie (1.0.0)
>
> heroku (1.18.1)
>
> highline (1.5.0)
>
> hpricot (0.8.4, 0.6.164)
>
> i18n (0.5.0)
>
> json (1.5.1, 1.4.6)
>
> launchy (0.3.7)
>
> less (1.2.21)
>
> libxml-ruby (1.1.2)
>
> liquid (2.2.2)
>
> mail (2.2.19, 2.2.15)
>
> mime-types (1.16)
>
> mocha (0.9.12)
>
> mongrel (1.1.5)
>
> multi_json (0.0.5)
>
> multi_xml (0.2.2)
>
> multipart-post (1.1.0)
>
> mutter (0.5.3)
>
> needle (1.3.0)
>
> net-scp (1.0.1)
>
> net-sftp (2.0.1, 1.1.1)
>
> net-ssh (2.0.4, 1.1.4)
>
> net-ssh-gateway (1.0.0)
>
> nokogiri (1.4.4)
>
> oauth (0.4.5, 0.4.4)
>
> polyglot (0.3.1)
>
> rack (1.2.1, 1.0.1)
>
> rack-mount (0.6.14, 0.6.13)
>
> rack-test (0.5.7)
>
> rails (3.0.9, 3.0.5, 2.3.5, 1.2.6)
>
> railties (3.0.9, 3.0.5)
>
> rake (0.8.7, 0.8.3)
>
> rant (0.5.7)
>
> rash (0.3.0)
>
> rdoc (3.9.2)
>
> RedCloth (4.1.1)
>
> rest-client (1.6.1)
>
> roauth (0.0.3)
>
> rspec (2.6.0, 2.5.0)
>
> rspec-core (2.6.4, 2.5.1)
>
> rspec-expectations (2.6.0, 2.5.0)
>
> rspec-mocks (2.6.0, 2.5.0)
>
> rspec-rails (2.6.1, 2.5.0)
>
> ruby-openid (2.1.2)
>
> ruby-yadis (0.3.4)
>
> rubygems-update (1.6.0)
>
> rubynode (0.1.5)
>
> sequel (3.20.0)
>
> shotgun (0.9)
>
> simple_oauth (0.1.4)
>
> sinatra (1.2.3, 1.0)
>
> spork (0.9.0.rc4)
>
> sqlite3 (1.3.3)
>
> sqlite3-ruby (1.2.4)
>
> stringex (1.2.2)
>
> sys-uname (0.8.5)
>
> taps (0.3.23)
>
> termios (0.9.4)
>
> thor (0.14.6)
>
> tilt (1.2.2)
>
> treetop (1.4.9, 1.4.5)
>
> tweetstream (1.0.4)
>
> twitter (1.4.0)
>
> twitter-stream (0.1.10)
>
> twitter4r (0.7.0)
>
> twitter_oauth (0.4.3)
>
> tzinfo (0.3.24)
>
> uuidtools (2.1.2)
>
> visionmedia-growl (1.0.3)
>
> webrat (0.7.1)
>
> xmpp4r (0.4)
>
> ZenTest (4.5.0)

Comment: I can do `require 'dm-postgres-adapter'` and that works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling dm-postgres-adapter 1.2.0.rc2 fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `dm-core` instead of `datamapper` in your `require` line.

Are you using Bundler?  Provided you have bundler set up correctly, it should already be loaded for you.